# Expected quotes function-url-quotes

Tags: stylelint

I need to use the following lines in my CSS to adjust the styling for an element only for Firefox browser.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
      right: -3px;
      @media (pointer: coarse) {
        right: 5px;
      }
    }
```

However, if I try to commit my code, I get this error:

> Expected quotes   function-url-quotes

How can I disable that Stylelint rule?

I tried this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line function-url-quotes
```

But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix('') {...}
```